# How do I add multiple "NOT LIKE '%?%' in the WHERE clause of sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 query like:

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%a%';
```

This would select all of the words where 'a' does not occur in the word. This I can get to work perfectly. The problem is if I want to further restrict the results to not include 'b' anywhere in the word. I am picturing something like this.

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT IN ('%a%', '%b%', '%z%');
```

which this obviously does not work, but this is the idea. Just adding an `AND` clause is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%a%' AND NOT LIKE '%b%';
```

If this is the only option then I will have to work with that, but I was hoping for something else.

Comment: It really is sqlite3 as far as my understanding goes. I am using the sqlite3 module in python. Not sqlite or sql... But I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use Sqlite's REGEXP support ( see the answer at [Problem with regexp python and sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365451/problem-with-regexp-python-and-sqlite) for how to do that ) , then you can do it easily in one clause:

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT REGEXP '[abc]';
```

Comment: For clarification for users not very familiar with regular expressions, it could be something like 'table' NOT REGEXP 'word1|word2|word3|word4|word5'; etc

Answer (score 92):

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%a%' 
AND word NOT LIKE '%b%' 
AND word NOT LIKE '%c%';
```

Comment: D'oh, I just made this mistake.  Thanks for catching the real problem: **omitting the left operand of the LIKE operator**. And thanks to the OP for thinning the embarrassment.

Answer (score 9):

this is a select command

```
   FROM
    user
WHERE
    application_key = 'dsfdsfdjsfdsf'
        AND email NOT LIKE '%applozic.com'
        AND email NOT LIKE '%gmail.com'
        AND email NOT LIKE '%kommunicate.io';
```

this update command

```
 UPDATE user
    SET email = null
    WHERE application_key='dsfdsfdjsfdsf' and  email not like '%applozic.com' 
    and email not like '%gmail.com'  and email not like '%kommunicate.io';
```

Answer (score 8):

You missed the second statement: 1) NOT LIKE A, AND 2) NOT LIKE B

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%a%' AND word NOT LIKE '%b%'
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you're avoiding the *[AND](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)* clause.  It is the simplest solution.

Otherwise, you would need to do an *[INTERSECT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php)* of multiple queries:

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%a%'
INTERSECT
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%b%'
INTERSECT
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%c%';
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression if your version of SQL supports it.

Comment: He is probably avoiding the AND clause because it makes the query so verbose. There should be some feature in SQL to combine multiple values in a list *a la* `NOT IN`, that way we only have to write `<value> NOT LIKE` once and then the list of values to compare. This is a reasonable wish and it's surprising that SQL does not have such a feature for this condition.

Comment: @TylerH It is difficult to talk about "SQL" in general for something like this. PostgreSQL, for example, has [`op any(array[...])` and `op all(array[...])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#idm46428706346880) constructs for this (with `in (list)` and `not in (list) being special cases of `=any` and `<> all`) , other SQL dialects do it differently. Similarly for regexes and the "standard" `similar to` pattern matching operator.

Answer (score 4):

The query you are after will be

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE word NOT LIKE '%a%' AND word NOT LIKE '%b%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have any problems with the "not like" query, 
Consider that you may have a null in the database. In this case, Use:

```
IFNULL(word, '') NOT LIKE '%something%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out below query which worked for me.

```
SELECT word FROM table WHERE  NOT (word LIKE '%a%' AND word LIKE '%b%');
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### Answer: Regular Expression
>
> Regular Expression aka Regex *(regexp)* are so powerful and used by almost every popular programming language.
> Using this you can find multiple patterns within few keystrokes instead of multiple AND, OR statement.
>
> Simple RegExp for the above solution:

> ```
> SELECT word FROM table WHERE word REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]*[^abz][a-zA-Z]*$';
> ```

> #### Here:
>
> `^` *represent the starting of the text*
> `[a-zA-Z]` *represent that any one character (upper/lower case) can take place*
> `*` *represent that whatever is preceded can be repeated 0 or more times*
> `[^abz]` *represent that, except these three characters any other character can take place - only single character*
> `$` *represent the ending of the text*

> Find a great example list [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/)