# PHP - get rows from a database where a word is not in a specific text

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database where I'm getting a random row from a table depending on a few variables. I'm trying to make it so it adds their username in this format (Admin, Jerry, Ben) once they view the advertisement (My project - clients view ads for Bitcoin). I want to make it so that once they view it , it adds their name in to a row called users_viewed_add (example is above). I need it to only get random rows based on if their username does not exist in the row users_viewed_add atoll so they can't view the ad more than once.

At the moment, I'm trying to do:

```
$query_second = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM business_advertisments WHERE ($users_credits >= amount_per_click) AND (users_viewed_add) NOT LIKE '$username' AND users_name != '$username' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

As you can see, the `AND (users_viewed_add) NOT LIKE '$username'` is not working for me as it's reading the text as a whole word. The problem is that I'm using comma's to seperate the usernames of the clients who have viewed the ad. Is there any work around for this ? I know the method to check a block of text but it wouldn't work in a SQL statement I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from this post: [How do I add multiple "NOT LIKE '%?%' in the WHERE clause of sqlite3 in python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089096/how-do-i-add-multiple-not-like-in-the-where-clause-of-sqlite3-in-python-c)

The correct SQL syntax to check a word doesn't exist in a row is:

```
AND users_viewed_add NOT REGEXP '[$username]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
AND CONCAT(',', users_viewed_add, ',') NOT LIKE '%,$username,%'
```

But you probably want to make a separated many to many table, and use user id instead of user name.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working. It's displaying rows where my username 'Admin' is in the users_viewed_add

Comment: Are you sure `$username` = Admin? Maybe you have spaces between commas?

Comment: oh yes I do , hold on. I will remove the spaces and try again.

Comment: yep, it's not working. https://gyazo.com/8aec8e9f0da8317a0ad8d157726b3fd5 https://gyazo.com/2ab7dfd242bde19be423e94b5c7064ae The bottom row is the one in the first image.

Comment: @BenZa It is working, take a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fcfd9/3. Play the id in the SELECT query so you can see that it's working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple values in your LIKE comparison, you can use:

```
AND users_viewed_add NOT LIKE ALL ('$username')
```

This will check that none of the $username values exists in the users_viewed_add field.  You may need to format your variable properly so the SQL works.

Comment: Hmm...nevermind, this is probably DB-specific and may not work on mysql.