# How to create a custom function in a QSqlDatabase: regex in sqlite and PyQT

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, qt, pyqt

We define the python type REGEXP function in sqlite and python following [Problem with regexp python and sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365451/problem-with-regexp-python-and-sqlite)

How can we do the same thing in PyQT, ie. with a QSqlDatabase?

More precisely, we use the REGEXP function to create a view:

```
Create view temp as select * from somewhere where columnname REGEXP 'myregex';
```

This works well, as long as we do the *select* from Python. We would like to show the result in a `QTableView` (via a `QSqlTableModel` filled with the view). As the view uses the REGEXP, we would have to link the Python *regex* function to the QSqlDatabase.

Comment: Unfamiliar with Qt but this question is unanswered for 2 years so what the heck: Can't QSqlTableModel select from the sqlite view? So QSqlTableModel "thinks" it's consulting a table for QTableView, but it's actually consulting the view which already has the regex in it? (I realize this might be nonsense, please don't sue)

Comment: Regexp support can be enabled via the [database connection options](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions) (i.e. `QSQLITE_ENABLE_REGEXP`).