# Using Python Regular Expression Code in SQLite SELECT Statement

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I'm trying to extract substrings from filenames stored in a table column, using a regular expression. So I'm using a custom python function:

```py
In [1]: import sqlite3, re
In [2]: def search(expr, item):
   ...:     return re.search(expr, item).group()
   ...:
In [3]: conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
In [4]: conn.create_function('SEARCH_REGEXP', 2, search)
In [5]: regexp = '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.(docx|pdf|rtf|doc)$'
In [6]: sql = "select SEARCH_REGEXP('%s', filename) from file_list;" % regexp
In [7]: cursor = conn.cursor()
In [8]: cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE "file_list" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, "filename" TE
   ...: XT);')
Out[8]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x1b7eafb7dc0>
In [9]: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO file_list(filename) VALUES ('filename.1.0.pdf'), ('filename.2.0.pdf');")
Out[9]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x1b7eafb7dc0>
In [10]: cursor.execute('select * from file_list;')
Out[10]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x1b7eafb7dc0>
In [11]: cursor.fetchall()
Out[11]: [(1, 'filename.1.0.pdf'), (2, 'filename.2.0.pdf')]
In [12]: cursor.execute(sql)
Out[12]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x1b7eafb7dc0>
In [13]: cursor.fetchall()
Out[13]: [('1.0.pdf',), ('2.0.pdf',)]
```

Now, I insert a value that will not match the reg exp:

```py
In [14]: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO file_list(filename) VALUES ('filename.pdf');")
Out[14]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x1b7eafb7dc0>
```

But this will now raise an exception:

```py
In [15]: cursor.execute(sql)
Out[15]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x1b7eafb7dc0>
In [16]: cursor.fetchall()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d35fc1caa8d6> in <module>
----> 1 cursor.fetchall()

OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception
```

How should I handle that, e.g. so the user-defined function returns an empty string in case of a no-match?

Thanks!

R.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365533/10366273 Have you tried a method like this instead? The way you are doing it seems a little weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, in your `search` function, `re.search(expr, item)` returns `None` when there is no match. Since `None` is not a `MatchObject`, an exception will be raised.

You can only call `group()` if there is a match :

```
def search(expr, item):
   result =  re.search(expr, item)
   if result != None:
        return result.group()
   else:
        return tuple() #See note below
```

NOTE: You also need to think about what should be done when there is no match in order to avoid  other similar issues. I'm returning an empty tuple here because `group()` returns a tuple, but you may want to do something else.