# How do you find regex matches in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table called `comments` with a column called `text`. I've been trying to make a SQL query that selects all rows where `text` fulfills the following regular expression: `(^|\\W)TEST(\\W|$)`. Currently, I'm using python to select all rows with `TEST`, then, running the regex test for each row that is returned. However, speed matters in what I'm doing, and it would be much faster if the SQL query had the regex matching. Here is the current query I have:

`SELECT text FROM comments WHERE text LIKE "%TEST%"`

How can I use regex in an SQLite query? If not regex, does SQLite have some similarly powerful text-matching syntax?

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: SQLite does not have native regex support, but there is a `REGEXP` operator which may be added on via a library.

Comment: Someone else solved this problem with python:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365451/problem-with-regexp-python-and-sqlite/5365533#5365533